# Calculating an octave binned abundance distribution of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, r, vector

I am using C++ to perform forward through time evolutionary simulations. To do this at each step some function is performed on a vector of longs

```
vector<long> population(popsize,1000);
```

and that new vector is stored within a vector of vectors every set time steps.

```
vector<vector<long>> populations;
```

This is done using

```
    for( int a = 1; a <= generations; a = a + 1 )
    {
        generationstep.generationstep(population, selection_strength,mutation_rate);
        if (a % pop_interval == 0)
        populations.push_back(population);}
```

where generationstep is a function that takes vector and parameters and performs a step in the simulation on it.

The vector populations contains a series of longs. Some of which appear multiple times, some which appear only once. Rather than storing the entire population i would like to find a way of extracting an abundance distribution (i.e a vector of frequency that each value appears). I then want to bin these abundance values into octave classes. In R this is easy an i can use the following code.

```
species_abundance_calculatore <- function(x){ # x is a vector equivalent to population vector in c++ code
    sortedtable <- sort(table(x[x > 0]),TRUE)
    speciesabundance <- as.vector(sortedtable) 
    loggedSA <- log2(speciesabundance)
    roundedSA <- floor(loggedSA)
    return(as.vector(table(factor(roundedSA, levels=0:max(roundedSA))))) # put into octave bins.}
```

However i am finding this alot more difficult in c++ partially due to lack of experience. I would ideally like to build an equivalent for an almost exact equivalence of this function in c++ so that i can do the following

```
for( int a = 1; a <= generations; a = a + 1 )
{
    generationstep.generationstep(population, selection_strength,mutation_rate);
    if (a % abundance_interval == 0)
    populations.push_back(species_abundance_calculator(population));}
```

Any guidance on how to go about doing this would be appreciated. I understand this this is a long question and am not expecting a complete answer, just some idea of where to start would be helpful (i'll update if / when i work through a complete solution).

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like for an end result. In the last example, would `species_abundance_calculator` return `vector<long>`? What exactly would the abundance distribution object contain? Perhaps you would like to consider `std::map`?

Comment: end result would be a vector. In the example from R it returns the last line (as.vector(table...roundedSA) etc.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what type of `vector` you have in mind. Perhaps someone with experience in R could answer. From a pure c++ perspective it might allow for an answer if you post the c++ function declaration (show values and types to be passed to the function and the return type) and add as much of the code you already have.

Comment: sorry if that was'nt clear.   In R you do not need to specify the type   that is returned so it's easy to move between ints and floats ( or longs and doubles). In this case the output and input and are both vectors<long> though one of the intermediary steps (logging) would involve a vector<double>/